# What does the following function do in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

```
private static function quote($str)
{
    return '"' . $str . '"';
}
```

and what does this mean too?

```
$args = array_map(array($this, 'quote'), $args);
```

I'm new to PHP and am trying to figure out my way through someone else's source code. Thanks!

Comment: Be aware that the output will be somewhat unexpected if any of the values in the array contain quotes already. [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json-encode) may be more suitable.

Answer (score 4):

It adds quotes to all values in an array.

Comment: It also shouldn't be called that way. It's declared as static but being called from an instance scope. It will work, but may confuse some people.